# SQL multiple statements with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, node-mysql

I'm trying to sort out SQL statements in one query for an authentication sequence.

**user**

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ emailAddress ║ password ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ test1        ║ pass1    ║
║  2 ║ test2        ║ pass2    ║
║  3 ║ test3        ║ pass3    ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════════╝
```

**user_token**

```
╔═══════╦═════════╗
║ token ║ user_id ║
╠═══════╬═════════╣
║ t1    ║       1 ║
║ t2    ║       2 ║
║ t3    ║       3 ║
╚═══════╩═════════╝
```

1. Check if record exists against and emailAddress and password
2. If a match is found then insert a token with user_id into user_token table
3. send back the user record in resultSet

**My Attempts (partial)** please note i can combine several sql statements delimited by `;`

1. Conditional Insert

   ```
   INSERT INTO user_token(token, user_id)
   SELECT ?, ? FROM DUAL
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user WHERE emailAddress = ? AND password = ?);

   ["t1", 1, "test1", "pass1"];
   ```
2. Setting some sort of variable, an attempt to combined with other attempts.

   ```
   SELECT @id:=id, emailAddress, password FROM user WHERE emailAddress = "test1" AND password = "pass1";
   ```
3. I think I'm close but having issues with access @id from outside the subquery.

   ```
   serviceRequest.sql = "INSERT INTO user_token(token, user_id)\
       SELECT ?, @id FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (
         SELECT @id:=id, emailAddress, password FROM user WHERE emailAddress = ? AND password = ?
       );
       SELECT @id, ? FROM DUAL";
   serviceRequest.values = ["t1", "test1", "pass1", "t1"];
   ```

**Objective**:

To combine multiple SQL statements employing logic in a single transaction/execution to achieve the authentication process, with the help of `IF` clause and user defined variables in SQL etc.

Comment: In MySQL, an `insert` does not return a record in a result set.

Comment: Hi Gordon, true, but I can have another SELECT statement followed or preceded by this that will return result set, mysql lib supports multipleStatements, I'm open to using user-defined variables as well `@id=id`; see my attempt #2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it down finally, but I need improvements for query #2, using IF instead of executing another `SELECT` statement inside `WHERE EXISTS` anyone?

```
serviceRequest.sql = "SET @emailAddress = ?, @password = ?;\
    SELECT @authToken:= ? AS authToken, @id:=id AS id FROM user WHERE emailAddress = @emailAddress AND password = @password;\
    INSERT INTO user_token(authToken, user_id) \
        SELECT @authToken, @id FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM user WHERE emailAddress = @emailAddress AND password = @password);";

serviceRequest.values = [request.body.credentials.emailAddress, request.body.credentials.password, "t3"];
```

**query #1**. First user record was retrieved and variables (`@token`, `@id`) are set and are returned as result set.

**query #2**. user_token insert will execute if record exists

Appreciate if someone can improve this answer and optimize the queries further, especially query #2 where I've another select statement going on, I believe the `WHERE EXISTS` could utilize checking if `@id` is not null for the insert to happen, and I don't have to pass username/password twice in `values` array.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `last_insert_id()` and `row_count()`.  To be safe, I would assign these to variables:

```
INSERT INTO user_token(token, user_id)
    SELECT ?, ? FROM DUAL
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user WHERE emailAddress = ? AND password = ?);

SELECT @row_count := ROW_COUNT(), @last_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

SELECT u.*
FROM user
WHERE @row_count > 0 AND emailaddress = ? and password = ?;
```

I'm not sure that is exactly what you want, but this does show the use of the two functions that you probably need.

Comment: let me explain the business logic, user table is populated already with several records, `a)` we check against their credentials (emailAddress/password) - `b)` if record exists insert a token into user_token(token, id), token is provided by me and id is the user retrieved from a, `c)` return the token with id as result set, (please note token is not an auto increment id, it's a random string)

Comment: I think I need these 3 or more sql "combined" statements in context of business logic explained above

Comment: I believe I'm close, can you please review my attempt #3, basically the @id is not accessible from outside the subquery. `Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'user_id' cannot be null`

Comment: Can you please look into my answer, not sure if this is something new to community here but I call them `"Intelligent compound SQL statements"` that saves us lot of programming code, I could substitute the whole logic in few combined sql statements, it was a long class implementation before in my code.