# mysql if return false if no record found

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

a typical scenario of user and products, I'd like the query to return 'false' if user is not assigned any product but it returns empty.

```
serviceRequest.sql = "SET @productId = ?;\
     SELECT IF(product.productId = @productId, 'true', 'false') AS entitled FROM user_token \
     INNER JOIN user_product ON user_token.user_id = user_product.user_id \
     INNER JOIN product ON user_product.product_id = product.id AND authToken = ? AND product.productId = @productId;";

serviceRequest.values = [request.query.productId, request.query.authToken];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` criteria is making it return empty instead of `false`.  This should work though using `outer joins` instead:

```
SELECT IF(ut.user_id IS NOT NULL, 'true', 'false') AS entitled 
FROM product p 
     LEFT JOIN user_product up ON p.id = up.product_id
     LEFT JOIN user_token ut ON up.user_id = ut.user_id 
                            AND ut.authToken = ?
WHERE p.productId = @productId;
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you started joining from product instead of user_token in my case, it's something I can never get my head around

Comment: This article might help (http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).  Basically you want to make sure you always return the product.  So you start from that table and `outer join` to the tables where the information is optional.  Since you want to check if a user exists or not, you `outer join` to that table and then you can check.  If you `inner join` to that table and the record doesn't exist, no results will come back.

Comment: thanks, also if you can please look into this to improve my answer to my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528816/sql-multiple-statements-with-conditions

Comment: Hi sgeddes, can you please tell me what if the productId is not existent in the database, is there a way to know if productId is not existent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN product.productId IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END
```